# How am I going to make this CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How am I going to turn

[image: this] into [image: this]

I tried to use `justify-content: space between;` and seperated the blocks, but how am I going to align 3 and 4 to the bottom of the container

CSS Code

```css
.container {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container > div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all these sizes are hard coded, you could do something like this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.container > div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container > div:nth-child(1),
.container > div:nth-child(2),
.container > div:nth-child(5) {
  order: -1;
}

.container > div:nth-child(5) {
  margin-inline: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How am I going to put the text in the center of the box, I used ```text-align: center``` to put the numbers in the middle of the box, but I can't change it vertically.

Comment: @henryChan Look into flexbox, that will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If only the size of your inside boxes are fixed you can use this solution.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.three {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
}

.four {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
}

.five {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="four">4</div>
  <div class="five">5</div>
</div>
```